# convert pandas with series of lists to np.array

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have the following sort of df:

```
c1           c2
foo123123   [bar782348, baz23423, foo423423423]
bar738475   [baz234234, foo4234234]
baz2323234  []
```

I need to map each value from `c1` to each item of lists of `c2` like

```
c1          c2
foo123123   bar782348
foo123123   baz23423
foo123123   foo423423423

bar738475   baz234234
bar738475   foo4234234
```

i can do this using `apply` in a rather weird way, but the speed does not work for me, as well as the code readability.

```
result = pd.DataFrame()
def func(row):
    global result
    df = pd.DataFrame([row['refs']], index=[row['id']]).stack().to_frame()
    df = df[[0]].reset_index()
    result = result.append(df)

df.apply(func,axis=1)
```

I am sure this can be done via `numpy` arrays manipulations, but I yet had not had much experience with numpy.

Thank you!

Comment: use explode for pandas `.25` and above `df.explode('c2')`

Comment: @anky_91, thank you, it's amazing

Comment: consider `df.reset_index()` if get unexpected result